# tikzscale not working with externalize using named only

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikzscale

I found a weird behavior when using `tikzscale` in combination with the `externalize`-library:

When I configure `externalize` with `only named = true`, but do not set `/pgfsetnextfilename` for an image, this image is not being scaled anymore.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
    only named=true,
]
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{simple.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
        \draw (1,0) -- (0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\tikzsetnextfilename{simple}  % no scaling is happening once this line is commented out
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{simple.tikz}

\end{document}
```

Is this an expected behavior, or did I miss something/ do something wrong?

EDIT: As expected, putting a `tikzexternaldisable` before the `\includegraphics` solves this problem.

Comment: Not externalizing is not a solution :D
Let's wait for someone to give more information and/or a solution. ;)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Actually, not externalising is the solution. That is precisely what is wanted. The problem is how to do this automagically given that **tikzscale** manages switches between externalisation and non-externalisation by relying on patches to the specific commands `\tikzexternalenable` and `\tikzexternaldisable`, which doesn't take account of other ways of enabling/disabling it - at least, not all other ways.

Comment: But if the picture is big.. it would be time consuming to compile it every time, wouldn't it be?

Comment: @cfr, you are right, not externalising is the desired solution.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis That's up to the document author ;). The code as written wants the picture not externalised but scaled. If externalisation was wanted, it would be named or another option would be used for externalisation which did not require naming ;).

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand all of the details, but I *think* that the problem is that **tikzscale** patches the commands `\tikzexternalenable` and `\tikzexternaldisable` but not `\tikzsetnextfilename`. This means that when externalisation is enabled, due to `\tikzsetnextfilename`, we get the patched commands which **tikzscale** has provided. When it is disabled because the picture is not named, the original, unpatched commands are in place and no scaling is done.

In contrast, if you switch using explicit `\tikzexternalenable` and `\tikzexternaldisable`, then everything works fine. But if you rely on implicit enabling and disabling *via* `\tikzsetnextfilename`, things don't work as expected.

The real fix for this is probably in the hands of **tikzscale**'s author or, if that's not practical, in the hands of the authors of TikZ/PGF and **tikzscale**.

As a workaround, you can patch `\tikzsetnextfilename` yourself to enable externalisation and set `\tikzexternaldisable` by default. However, I cannot currently work out how to issue `\tikzexternaldisable` automatically afterwards, so below I've issued this manually, which is not altogether satisfactory.

But perhaps this will be of some help, at least.

```
\begin{filecontents}{siml.tikz}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
        \draw (1,0) -- (0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usetikzlibrary{external,backgrounds}
\tikzexternalize
[
    only named=true,
]
\tikzexternaldisable
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pretocmd{\tikzsetnextfilename}{\tikzexternalenable}{\typeout{Patch OK!}}{\typeout{Oh dear!}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{siml.tikz}

\tikzsetnextfilename{siml}  % no scaling is happening once this line is commented out
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{siml.tikz}

\tikzexternaldisable
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{siml.tikz}
\end{document}
```

I reduced the scaling a bit to fit things on one page:

[image: scaled pictures]

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. Suppose `externalize` is switched off because `\tikzsetnextfilename` was NOT used: why should `tikzscale` use any of the makros of `externalize` then? Shouldn't the whole process of plotting and scaling the tikz-picture then be similar to the one where I did not load `externalize` in the first place?
Maybe something to point out to the authors of tikzscale indeed.

Comment: @Dux There are complications. Even when a particular picture is not externalised, it isn't always quite as if you were not externalising at all. And **tikzscale** patches the commands TikZ uses at the beginning of the document and then each time `\tikzexternalenable` and `\tikzexternaldisable` is used. I'm guessing that after the picture following a named picture, TikZ restores the original definitions without using `\tikzexternaldisable` directly, so that the patched commands are no longer active.

Comment: You might be right, indeed. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @Dux I think it would be worth emailing the maintainer of **tikzscale** to report the problem, maybe asking for this method of externalisation to be supported or, failing that, for the documentation to make clear that the package requires externalisation to be handled in specific ways.